# Do R plots have handles?

Tags: r

Do plots in R have handles? For example, if I were to use something like this:

```
plot(plotData[,1], plotData[,2], type='l', col='red', lty=2, xlab='x', 
    ylab='y', main='sample plot')
```

would I be able to change anything in this plot later like the color, or the x-axis label, or the x-axis range, etc.? Or do I have the plot this all over again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base `R` does not have handles in the sense that you are asking. Although you *can* modify some aspects of the plot after you've plotted it, much better suited to the needs in question would be to use `ggplot`

You can save the output to an object and append as needed.
You can also use `last_plot()`

Have a look at 
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/ and http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/